# Using react scripts alongside vite

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, vite

I’ve migrated my react typescript app to vite, and “removed all references to react-scripts” as the instructions say. But now I’m trying to get jest to work, and even looking at a dozen answers, guides, tutorials, etc, I still can’t get all the tests to run without errors about invalid use of “import” etc. nor can I get vitest to work as a simple drop-in.

Is there any reason I can’t just leave react-scripts in my repo to run its test script, and still have vite for dev and build?